# How to "clean up" a PHP array?

Tags: php

How can I make a PHP array look a bit better for a web chat application im making? I have it nested by concatenating HTML `<pre>` tags with a mySQL table using MySQLi. I just want it to be presented in a more fashionable way, if there's a better way to display an array that looks good.

It looks like this right now:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => this is a test
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => testing
        )

)
1
```

And what I'm going for is something like this (it doesn't have to be exact, just somewhat "cleaner"):

```
[0] => this is a test
[1] => testing
```

Any help would be appriciated!

I've tried using `$string = str_replace(array(']]',']]'),'',$string);` with parenthesis too, but then people cant type those characters. I've also tried lightly looking through the documentation and google.

Edit: Here is the code snippet of how I'm getting it from the database, I use fetch all:

```
$rows = mysqli_fetch_all($result);
$result -> free_result();
echo "<pre>", print_r($rows), "</pre>";
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. We need a little bit more context. Why is the original array nested? Where does it come from? Which data structure could occur? Is it only a question of pretty printing the array content? Or would you like to transform the array itself? Please edit your question and provide further information.

Comment: It's unusual to use functions like `var_dump` or `print_r` to present data to the user except for debugging purposes. What is the actual presentation you want to display? In general you would use loops or array functions to generate HTML code or JSON on AJAX requests.

Comment: @PinkeHelga I just edited my post with some more context if that helps

Comment: Please add your PHP code. Likely what you're doing should be refactored. I'd guess you are using fetchall.

Comment: @super15 So you have that as a string or do you have the PHP array at hand to disply?

Comment: @user3783243 Okay I made an edit. I should have done that a bit ago, sorry

Comment: @super15 Don't use `mysqli_fetch_all` use https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php and build the array as you need.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as you intend to convert a nested array into a plain one. This can be achieved by the `array_column` function.

```
$source =
[
  [ 'this is a test' ],
  [ 'testing' ],
];

$plain_array = array_column($source, 0);

var_dump($plain_array);
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  [0] =>
  string(14) "this is a test"
  [1] =>
  string(7) "testing"
}
```

However, this is not the form we want to present to a user. If the php result is the response to a normal request, we usually generate HTML code, e.g. an unordered list. This can be achieved by a loop or an array function like that:

```
$li = array_reduce($plain_array, function ($aggregate, $value) { return "$aggregate<li>$value</li>"; });
$list = "<ul>$li</ul>";
```

The result looks like that:

```html
<ul><li>this is a test</li><li>testing</li></ul>
```

If the PHP script responds to an AJAX request, most likely you want to respond in the JSON format (which will be processed by JavaScript on the client side):

```
$json = json_encode($plain_array);
```

which results in:

```
["this is a test","testing"]
```

Comment: Thanks, but it just displays the "top part" of the array, like this:

• Array
• Array